# Read html after span using VBA

Tags: html, vba

I'm looking for some help to figure how to pull out "60 min" out of the html file using VBA.

```
 <span class="item">Boil Size:</span> 13.71 gal<br>
 <span class="item">Boil Time:</span> 60 min<br>
 <span class="item">End of Boil Vol:</span> 11.86 gal<br>
```

Using

```
Set SpanList= htm.getElementsByTagName("span")
```

I can figure out that a specific SpanList(1) is "Boil Time", but I don't have a way to see the text after it.

Comment: You should had included the 60min inside the span tag.

Comment: This isn't my html page that I'm trying to read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text following the span is within the next text node and extends to the `<br>` so to read its value:

```
value = SpanList(1).nextSibling.nodeValue
```

(Then `LTrim()` to remove the space)